# Excel : MAX number in any 30 day period

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max

I`m trying to work out a formula, on how to get the MAX amount, for any 30 day consumption period, for a certain item, when all the criteria are in one data table. See picture below. Date is in column A.

[image: Columns o Master Data]

I have table with a formula where I copy and paste data manually

```
=SUM(IF([Date]>[@Date]-30,IF([Date]<=[@Date],[Amount])))
```

[image: Manualy gathered date from master file]

At the end- I would like to have the list of all the item numbers in one column and the one next to it should have - max amount used in any 30 day period.

In my Master file I have around 1300 Item numbers, which is time-consuming to get the MAX data on-by-one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure it's what you're looking for, but depending on your version of Excel you could use the `MAXIFS` function. If that's not available, there are examples online using `MAX` and `IF` to get the same result.

Comment: @BigBen I’ve tried, can’t seem to find any formulas this time. I do a lot of research online but this time no luck.

Comment: @BigBen I’m looking for a formula, which would calculate MAX amount used in any 30 day period. Example- Item number 12345, which would be in column A, is used 312 times, that is in column B. All the data, over 65000 rows is In sheet1 and the calculation is In sheet2. Hope this  helps.

Comment: So the "max" formula should return 117 in that same example?

Comment: @BigBen No. It should be- 312

In the first picture, you see an example of data I download from my software. . A,B,C,D,E, F,G,H.

A - contains the list of used dates
B, C, D, F, G - irrelevant for this formula.
E - item numbers, for whom I need the data or. contains approx 1300 units
H - contains amount used (was originaly visible, when I shared a link to the picture)

In the second picture you see a table, where I have the formula working already, but on the condition that I get the data manually from the downloaded data - Column A and Column H, and copy it in to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copy and paste, you can do a pivot table on the data in the first screenshot. Use the dates in rows, use the Amount in values. If you want to do this for item numbers, use them in rows before the date.

You should then have a nice table with dates and amounts per date, no duplicate dates.

If you don't want to use pivot tables, create the date column manually, without duplicates, and use a Sumifs formula to sum the data from the original sheet. Enter the start date, then use the fill handle and drag down. That will automatically increment the date. Let's say the dates are in column A, first row has labels, then use in B2 and copy down:

```
=sumifs('the other sheet'!H:H,'the other sheet'!A:A,A2)
```

Next, in C2 you can use a MAXIFS function along the lines of

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,"<="&A2-30)
```

Comment: Thank you, Teylyn! I used pivot table to create a drop down list for the item numbers and got the required data aligned just as I wanted to. Thank you, for taking time to help me!